# On divisors of Mersenne numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we prove that $M_n=2^n-1$ does not have any divisors between $\sqrt{3M_n}$ and $\sqrt{5M_n}$?

Answer (score 6):

You **cannot** prove it because $M_{11}=2^{11}-1 = 2047 = 23*89$ indeed **has** a factor between 
$\sqrt{3M_{11}} \approx 78.36$ and $\sqrt{5M_{11}}\approx 101.17$